# Match string entries by regexp and create splitted array in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
const str = 'my string is awesome <%010203%> and super cool <%090807%>'
```

Where symbols in the `<%%>` is ids.
I have a function that gets some data by that id `getDataById(id)`. I want to create an array from this string that should look like this:

```
const arr = ['my string is awesome ', getDataById('010203'), ' and super cool ', getDataById('090807')]
```

How can i do it? Thank you

Comment: For future reference, you should include what you have tried so far and where you are having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not know what you have tried I can't help with your understanding of where you might have found difficulty with this.

So, starting from zero it appears you would need to split the string into parts and replace the value for only the parts that match the ID format with a function call. Luckily, the split occurs where the replacement also occurs.

Solving the first part, we can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a regex as a separator and also using a capture to include the ID part in the output.

```
str.split(/<%(\d+)%>/)
```

*If we did not include the capture for the ID, the separator would not be included in the output.*

Now for the conversation of the ID to a function call. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is perfect for iterating over an array (the output of `split`) and converting it to a new array with a transformation for each element. However since we only want to replace the IDs with the function call we won't need to transform every value. This means we will need to test when to or not to transform a value.

For the testing, a simple approach could be to use another regex to see if the value is an ID format but, however odd, it could be possible to have a false-positive match of a non-ID string.

Another approach is that since the output of the split is an array like:

```
['some string', ID, 'some other string', ID, 'this could look like an ID', ID, ...]
```

then we can quickly see that the ID is every other element of the array. Using a [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) (or modulo) on the index value of the iteration then would allow us to quickly and with certainty know that we have an ID.

```
arr.map((val, index) => index % 2 ? getDataById(val) : val)
```

```js
const str = 'my string is awesome <%010203%> and super cool <%090807%>';

const arr = str
  .split(/<%(\d+)%>/)
  .map((v, i) => i % 2 ? `getDataById('${v}')` : v); // outputting with template to show desired value
  
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding everything to an array like that is slightly awkward simply replacing the values in the string would be easier. If that would work for you then here is a simple implementation of that.

```js
const str = 'my string is awesome <%010203%> and super cool <%090807%>';

function getDataById(id) {
  return '(My data: ' + id + ')';
}

console.log(str.replace(/<%(\d+)%>/g, getDataById('$1')));
```

We're matching any of the tags by matching `<%` followed by a capture case of 1 or more digits followed by a `%>`. We are then replacing that with our `getDataById()` function and passing in the value of our capture case.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it is not exactly what I need. I need exactly array like i mentioned. Because later i need to build DOM based on that array. If string - render string inj usual span, otherwise - make some calculations and convert data received by `getDataById()` to specifix dom element